# php7 fileInfo extension , for upload. Failed to load magic database at 'null ' .what files have i forgotten?

Tags: php, fileinfo

i can't upload file on php ,even if i install the two magic files into extras/file directory; and; create magic environnment variable.

[image] for the ddl=> where i put it.
[image] the two files where come from php.net for the extension fileInfo.
[image]the error i get.
i Enable the extension, and it is the same, it's doesn't work. Could you help me ?
my symfony 4 code:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $fileConstraints=[
            new File(array(
                'maxSize' => '20M',
                'mimeTypes' => array(
                    'application/pdf'
                ),
                'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF document',
            ))
        ];
        $builder

            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('plainPassword',RepeatedType::class,[ 'type'=>PasswordType::class,
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
                'first_options'=>['label'=>'Password'],
                'second_options'=>['label'=>'Repeat Password'],

            ])

            ->add('telephone')

            ->add('file', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType::class, array('label' => 'Fichier','constraints'=>$fileConstraints))

            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ]);

    }
```

could you help me,what should i do please ?

Comment: how does it know to look in the `extras/file` folder? is there some configuration in php.ini?

Comment: uncommented extension fileinfo line

Answer (score 0):

ok , I have Succeded ,

-I remove the MAFIC environment on Windows
-I change orm Entity type of variable $file for string to blob

And now It's work  !:)